# Which one of the Google Analytics stats should be my top priority to improve SEO: visits, pageviews, bounce rate, new visitors, or visit duration

Tags: seo, google-analytics

My site is getting a lot of traffic from an image (a company logo image) because this image is ranked 1st in Google search results for a company's title. (I have no idea how that happened.)

This image is must for my website, but it is not relevant to the site content, so irrelevant people search for the image and find out about my site.  I get interesting statistics:

[image: site statistics]

```
Pros: Total Visits & Avg. New Visits
Cons: Avg. Page/Visit, Avg. Visit Duration, Bounce Rate
```

I am confused if this image is helpful to my website. I don't know what the balance between those 5 statistics should be.  My website is 2 months old, and we are working on SEO at the moment.

Edit: here are the details about the image:

- **Search Keyword:** arcelik logo
- **Search Site:** google.com.tr
- **[Search URL](https://www.google.com.tr/search?hl=en&q=arcelik+logo&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.41524429,d.Yms&biw=1366&bih=667&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&ei=oZIDUfutAseVswa9zYHwCw)**

Comment: With only ~55 visits, the stats are largely meaningless.  It's not enough data to really analyze and come up with any kind of trend.  Are you excluding your own visits?

Comment: share the google image search url....

Comment: @JCL1178 don't think of it as 55 visits, think of it as %5 of total visits. Also I don't search for this image, so I am excluded from statistics.

Comment: @bybe I have edited the question,

Comment: Google does not use Google Analytics data for ranking purposes.

Comment: @JohnConde but analytics data gives ideas, even it is not exactly related, it is somehow related.

Comment: @JohnConde Engagement Rates from the visitors play a major role for ranking. With the help of Google Analytics, webmasters can identify the engagement rates, adjust their landing pages/content accordingly to improve interaction times and rankings indirectly? Please enlighten me if I am missing anything.

Comment: How would Google know a website's engagement rate? And what qualifies as engagement? Can you cite any reputable sources from Google?

Answer (score 2):

To be honest, I feel like this question is kind of missing the point a little bit.

SEO can either be defined as the technical, all-encompassing field or strictly technical optimization. Either way, I think you're kind of looking at this in the wrong way.

The whole point of Google's algorithm updates, every update, is to weed out spam and produce higher quality websites for users. Delivering them the intent of their query. The more well designed a website is and the more relevant to the intent of their original search query, the better you're going to do. That being said, each of these metrics is pseudo-important to SEO for different reasons. I wouldn't focus on one. Instead, try to focus on what each one is telling you. @Prasad and @RanjanMishra make good points, but I'm going to go a little deeper.

1. Visits - This is overall how you're doing. Not the best metric, since you can't really affect this directly. It's going to be driven by whether or not you meet your users' needs and that will influence how well you rank in the SERPs.
2. Pages / Visit - As Prasad said, this is a fair metric (but not the only one!). Basically, the more pages your users look at, the more you are *hopefully* addressing the needs they have. Google tracks at how long users stay on your pages and the general structure of your website. If users spend a while on your site without going idle and look at stuff on each page for more than a minute or two, it assumes they have found something valuable. Careful, though, it may also be that people are having trouble finding what they're looking for. Which leads us into bounce rate.
3. Avg. Visit Duration - As I've said, Google tracks how long a user is on your site. The best possible thing is the user comes to your site, finds what they need after a few minutes, and closes their browser or moves on to something else. Unless you're a news site, you don't want users on your pages for 20-30 minutes, but 1-2 minutes is usually a bad sign, too. Depending on what you do, this is hard to gauge, but I'd say it's pretty important.
4. % New Visits - At the moment, you have so few visitors, it's really hard to judge this. You don't want 100% new visitors because it means no one ever finds what they're looking for on your site, which is bad for how you'll rank in the SERPs. On the other hand, if you have 100% returning visitors, it means you're not ranking well and can't attract new users and grow your site. It's a delicate balance. I'd say 30-40% returning users is a good balance, but that's just me.
5. Bounce Rate - When looking at bounce rate, the worst possible thing is someone spending a bit of time on your site, hitting the back button and re-writing their search query. If they looked for 'red kids shoes' and your site sells red shoes and children's shoes, but you don't have any red kids shoes, that's bad. It means the user will get frustrated, go back to Google and type something like 'children shoes in red' or 'red kids sketchers' or something similar. This proves to Google that you DO NOT HAVE what the searcher was looking for. The more this happens, the worse you'll perform for certain queries. This is why bounce rate is important. Like @Ranjan said, you should definitely pay attention to this. The lower it is, the happier your users are. The happier your users are, the better you'll end up doing in the SERPs.

Like I said, I don't think these are strictly important or good metrics for the technical side of SEO, as in what you've optimized, but it is good if you consider the SEO definition of 'a good site users want to be on' which makes Google happy and generally leads to better ranking. Hope that helps!

Comment: Great in depth answer.  I'd give it two votes up if I could.

Comment: Thank you! ^_^ It comes from working as an SEO and reading blogs for an hour or two every morning from two years. I have trouble citing sources because it's all just from experience now.

Answer (score 1):

I think bounce rate is very important: it makes your website rankings improve. If bounce rate is less than 50% then you will get good traffic.  Then visitors will be keen to see your website with much curiosity and zeal.

Answer (score 1):

I would focus on pages/visit metric and try to increase that. If you want to do this, start writing related content to that logo (if possible).